# (a+++++b) doesn't work, while (a++-++b) works

Tags: java, prefix, postfix-mta

Why do I get an error in this program?

If I change the middle operator to minus like this `(a++-++b)`, it is executing without any error:

```
class Demo
{  
    public static void main(String []args){

        int a=10;
        int b=20;

        System.out.println (a+++++b);

     }
}
```

Comment: format your snippet correctly and then add some details about the problem you are facing

Comment: compiler error, runtime error, full message, expected result, received result.

Answer (score 1):

The parser is unable to see what you want it to see. You want it to see

```
(a+++++b)
```

as

```
(a++ + ++b)
```

but, the parser is seeing it as

```
(a++++ +b)
```

and therefore, it is throwing a compilation error as ++ operator is expecting a variable but it is getting a++, which is a value.

Answer (score 0):

The subtract sign works because it is identified as a separate operator from the series of additions. The additions however appear to become one string of operators. if you just add a space between the addition signs it should work fine as it will identify the addition operator separately.. eg System.out.println(a++ + ++b);

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=10;
        int b=20;
        System.out.println(a++ + ++b);
    }
}
```

// output
31

I think you might want this, don't use +++ it's not valid operator in java,
BTW, you should post better question next time.

Comment: `-++` or `++-` aren't valid operators too.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
(a++-++b);
```

The parser knows, that there is no such thing as an +- or -+ operator on int. So it can split the expression in (a++ - ++b);

For

```
(a+++++b);
```

This can be (a+ ++... or (a++ +... but let's first have a look at a simpler expression:

```
int a = 100;
int b = 0;
-> int c=a+++b;
|  Added variable c of type int with initial value 100
```

What is the desired result? a++ +b or a+ ++b? Well, it's interpreted as c=
(a++)+b; but it's bad style, since you have to have the details of operator precedence in head.

Is ++++b allowed, or a++++?

```
-> ++++b;
|  Error:
|  unexpected type
|    required: variable
|    found:    value
|  ++++b;
|    ^-^

-> a++++;
|  Error:
|  unexpected type
|    required: variable
|    found:    value
|  a++++;
|  ^-^
```

No. Why not? You could argue, that it is (a++)++; or ++(++b); But both include two steps, increment by one and returning a value, so for

```
a=100
b=0
c=a++;
c=++b;
```

we know, that c will become 100 or 1, in one case, the return is performed before incrementing (c=a++), in the other case after (++b);

Now what should happen with ++++b; or ++(++b); What get's returned?

Considering that, the only valid interpretation for a+++++b is a++ + ++b; There is no a+ ++ ++b, nor a+ +++ +b.

And a++ + ++b; works:

```
-> c=a++ + ++b;
|  Variable c has been assigned the value 101
```

But since it is very rarely used, and not a big deal to insert two spaces, and more reader friendly, anyhow, we should live with the inconsistency, of a+++++b being rejected, while a++-++b is allowed, which doesn't make the latter a nice to read expression. Horizontal spaces make code better parsable for humans too, and that should be your main concern.

If you like to drive someone crazy, use

```
c=a--- - --b;
```

since there is this unary -, which is handy for producing negative values like -7.

Answer (score 0):

Here, as + operator and  ++ operator have equal precedence (similarly, - and -- have equal precedence.) So, +++ and --- gives an error as it will be broken into '+' and  '++' ('-' and '--').

To solve this error, we can use +(++).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

a+++++b ,a++---b,a------b and a--+++b will throw an error because + and ++ have same precedence.So Java will throw invalid argument for +++b,---b,---b and +++b respectively.